# How to stop people trolling and deleting my Database in mysql shared server?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

in my school we have to work on shared mysql server which means anyone can access anyone's db, and also delete it by using 'drop database databasename;', so how can i stop it?

Is there any possible way to 'undo' it?(within seconds) i tried looking it up online but i couldnt find anything to undo a drop database command?

Comment: When you create your db, configure it so only you have access rights to it, if thats something your account is allowed to do. Otherwise do a regular backup

Comment: Have you tried asking your teacher/professor to do something about this? And, unless you're creating backups, I don't believe you can restore your DB after it is dropped.

Comment: A backup can be made (using MySqlWorkbench) via the menu 'Server/Data Export'.

Comment: Without being able to grant specific permissions I'd probably look at taking regular backups using `mysqldump`

Comment: Hot take: Don't submit anything, blame the teacher for creating an unsecured DB and say that your work was deleted by another student. Hotter take: Delete all the databases yourself. (In all reality, this kind of roadblock is caused by the teacher's lack of foresight, not by difficulty in the assignment. It merits a convo about proper credential/access management).

Comment: For the record, there is no undo for DROP DATABASE.

Comment: Thanks everyone!, i think the best option i have is to complain to the teacher, but the student doing this is teachers pet so i dont know if it will work out.

Comment: @Rogue does deleting a database somehow logs it so that the admin can check which computer it was which deleted the db?

Comment: It does, but if they're providing the same credentials to students to an unsecured DB, they're not likely the kind capable of finding that. It was more of a sarcastic suggestion, but one you could mention to them.

Comment: Another suggestion: Just set up your own mysql server to test with (a good exercise itself imo).